# MySQL about employee and staff and nulls using joins

Tags: mysql, join, null, inner-join

i have three tables

Employee 
empId int pk 
empname varchar

customersite 
empid int pk fk 
custid int pk fk 
startdate date pk 
enddate date

employeeassignment 
custid int pk 
sitename varchar

my question is

How to show the name of all our employees with the site name of those who are on customer sites today. For those who are not on customer site today, show thier name and 'N/A' for the site name.

i have so far

```
SELECT
e.EmpName,
cs.SiteName
FROM
EmployeeAssignment ea
INNER JOIN
Employee e
ON
e.EmpId = ea.EmpId
INNER JOIN
CustomerSite cs
ON
cs.CustId = ea.CustId
```

which give me all employee at work today, with their name and the site.

any help you be very appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an outer join instead of an inner join:

```
SELECT e.EmpName, IFNULL(cs.SiteName, 'N/A') AS SiteName
FROM Employee e 
LEFT JOIN EmployeeAssignment ea ON e.EmpId = ea.EmpId 
LEFT JOIN CustomerSite cs ON cs.CustId = ea.CustId
```

You may also want to add other conditions, for example to restrict the dates.

Comment: most of that work had to swap it to ISNULL because i'm using MySQL server. how could i introduce there dates because if i use WHERE CLAUSE it will cut the selection to only people working today

Comment: wait there figured it out needed to add AND after the e.EmpId = ea.EmpId. Thanks

Comment: `ISNULL` is Microsoft SQL Server syntax. MySQL uses `IFNULL`. And yes, you can use `ON ... AND ...` to restrict the dates.